# Complex Model Associations - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, models, model-associations

So I have a bit of a complex model association setup that I can't seem to get quite right.

I have:

```
                           Owners     Doors     
    Clients -> Orders -> <    |     /
                           Property - Windows
                                    \
                                      Heating/Cooling
```

So the thought process is that **each property** can have many **doors, windows, heating/cooling systems, and owners**, and each **owner** can have many **property**.

When an **order** is submitted with only the **owner** and **property** info (address, etc), we go and find how many **doors, windows, heating/cooling systems the property has**, update the **order**, and then sent it back to the **client**.

Right now I have my models setup that, (condensed here for space saving)

```
Clients has_many :orders

Order -> belongs_to :property, :clients
Order -> has_many :doors, :windows, :heating/cooling, through: :property

Property -> has_many :doors, :windows, :heating/cooling, :owners
Doors, Windows, Heating/Cooling, Owners -> belongs_to :property
```

So my problem is that I want to be able to know what doors, windows, and heating/cooling were pulled on which order. So I'd say that they should belong to order BUT if multiple orders come in on the same property, I don't want to have the same information for those models in my db multiple times for said property just because they come in on a different order, and likewise want to be able to look up the property itself and see all associated orders, doors, windows, heating/cooling.

I hope my explanation was clear as I'm still fairly new to rails and how the associations work and their capabilities so any insight would be super helpful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the quickest approach would be to add an `order_ids` column, serialized as an array, onto the doors/windows/heating/cooling tables. You'd need application logic to maintain column state though.

Unrelated: are the doors/windows/heating/cooling models unique enough that doing something like an `items` table and have it be polymorphic wouldn't work?

Comment: The doors/windows/heating/cooling models are unique enough to warrant their own models/tables. While some properties overlap (size, surface area, etc) they have many of their own properties.

My initial thinking was to have each model `belongs_to` both `property` AND `orders` but my concern is that if an order is put through for an existing property where we already know what kind of doors or windows it has, the order will create a new doors or windows records and not reference the current ones. I'm wondering if I should set the models to polymorphic and connect them on join tables to both.